# Gridview Update is not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
            {
                    string Createid =((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblID")).Text;
                    string Client_Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtClientName")).Text;
                    string Client_Contact_Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtContactPerson")).Text;
                    string Client_Contact_Role = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPosition")).Text;
                    string Client_Contact_Email_ID = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMailID")).Text;
                    string Phone_Number = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPhNumber")).Text;
                    string No_of_Openings = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtOpenings")).Text;
                    string Technology = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTech")).Text;
                    string Status = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStatus")).Text;
                    string Op_Start_Date = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStrtDate")).Text;
                    string Op_End_Date = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndDate")).Text;
            con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Client_Det set Client_Name=@Client_Name, " + " Client_Contact_Name= @Client_Contact_Name, " + " Client_Contact_Role= @Client_Contact_Role, " + " Client_Contact_Email_ID = @Client_Contact_Email_ID , " + " Phone_Number= @Phone_Number , " + "No_of_Openings=@No_of_Openings ,  " + "Technology=@Technology, " + "Status=@Status, " + " Op_Start_Date=@Op_Start_Date , " + " Op_End_Date=@Op_End_Date where Createid= @Createid", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                    gvbind();


                }
```

My table datatypes

[image]

The above are the table datatype.

After Clicking on update button it is not even showing any errors

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" align="center"
             DataKeyNames="Createid" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
             OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
             OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
                EnableViewState="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
    <Columns>


<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("Createid")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Client">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblClientName" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Client_Name")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientName" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Client_Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Contact Person">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblContactPerson" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Client_Contact_Name")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactPerson" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Client_Contact_Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactPerson" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Position">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPosition" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Client_Contact_Role")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosition" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Client_Contact_Role")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosition" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Mail ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMailID" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Client_Contact_Email_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMailID" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Client_Contact_Email_ID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMailID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Phone Number">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPhNumber" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Phone_Number")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhNumber" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Phone_Number")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "No of Openings">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblOpenings" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("No_of_Openings")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOpenings" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("No_of_Openings")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOpenings" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Technology">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTech" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Technology")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTech" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Technology")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTech" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>  
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Start Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStrtDate" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Op_Start_Date","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStrtDate" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Op_Start_Date","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStrtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>   
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "End Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Op_End_Date","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("Op_End_Date","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate> 
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />


        </Columns>



</asp:GridView>
```

This my source code for the gridview...
Have i done anything wrong in providing correct fields .. please let me know

Comment: Any errors you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors... but after clicking update it is not updating.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see if you have a value in each variable and your query is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Your Update query doesn't do anything. Either you should assign it as parameter or you should give the variable name directly.

**Option 1**

---

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Client_Det set Client_Name='"+ Client_Name +"', Client_Contact_Name='"+ Client_Contact_Name +"', Client_Contact_Role='"+Client_Contact_Role+"', Client_Contact_Email_ID ='"+ Client_Contact_Email_ID+"', Phone_Number='"+Phone_Number+"', No_of_Openings='"+No_of_Openings+"', Technology='"+Technology+"', Status='"+Status+"', Op_Start_Date='"+ Op_Start_Date +"', Op_End_Date='"+Op_End_Date+"' where Createid='"+Createid+"'", con);
```

There variables where not properly referred. So the values were not getting attached into query.

> **PS - This is very bad way to write query in perspective of security. Your code keep space open to SQL injection attack. Option 2 will be a better way to write queries**

**Option 2**

---

*`Through Command parameters`*

So this is basically you are assigning values to parameters and parameter name given to command parameters should be equal to the parameter name given in the query. So below is just a glimpse of how you can achieve.

```
string sql = "UPDATE Client_Det set Client_Name=@Client_Name, Client_Contact_Name= @Client_Contact_Name, Client_Contact_Role= @Client_Contact_Role, Client_Contact_Email_ID = @Client_Contact_Email_ID , Phone_Number= @Phone_Number ,No_of_Openings=@No_of_Openings, Technology=@Technology,Status=@Status,Op_Start_Date=@Op_Start_Date, Op_End_Date=@Op_End_Date where Createid= @Createid";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_Name", Client_Name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_Contact_Name",Client_Contact_Name) 
/*Add for remaining param values*/


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
gvbind();
```

1st parameter on each `AddValueWith` i.e. `@Client_Name` and `@Client_Contact_Name` should be same as given in `update query` and 2nd parameter i.e. `Client_Name` and `Client_Contact_Name` are value fetched from `GridView Controls` like `TextBox`, `Label` etc.,

Comment: I tried as you given the code... but still same problem... it is not getting updated... and still the page is in Edit mode only..

Thank you for the Suggestion

Comment: Place a `debugger` in the code and check? also wrap your code in `try catch` block, check to see if you have any exception